# rpm build will remove .symtab/.strtab section?

Tags: debugging, gcc, rpm, elf, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build a binary with .symtab and .strtab section to trace functions.
I'm using "make && make install", the binary is ok.
But when I use "make rpm" and install rpm package, both of .symtab and .strtab section are gone which is weired.
I track the rpm build log, and saw those:

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c mybinary /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mybinary.el7.centos.x86_64/usr/sbin/mybinary
```

and here, I executed it manually again, the .symtab section exists.

```
extracting debug info from /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mybinary.el7.centos.x86_64/usr/sbin/mybinary
```

After this step, the .symtab section is gone, I guess there's something wrong here. But I don't know why.
Please help.

Comment: I got the answer from here: https://www.technovelty.org/code/split-debugging-info-symbols.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rpmbuild automatically strip debuging info and place it in -debug subpackage. If you want to preserve it for some reason follow https://imvoid.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/stripping-and-stopping-stripping-of-binaries-in-rpm-build/

Comment: yes, that's my choice right now, do not build debuginfo package and do not strip debug sections. My original goal was that build both the normal and debuginfo rpm package, and binary in normal package contains .symtab .strtab and .debug_* sections. It seems like there's no way to do this. :(